# How to have select distinct of all but last column , and last column as comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I have a table with following structure. It has 8 columns where 1st 7 some time contain duplicate and last one can have different values (no unique though).

[image]

How do I select distinct for 1st 7 columns and then show the last column as comma separated values.

So the last column should look like following,

[image]

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the distinct 7 values in a sub-query and then perform the XML STUFF to consolidate the values

Please note the **"--Add your other fields here"**

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,CollectionDate  = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +cast(CollectionDate as varchar(max))
                                 From  YourTable 
                                 Where Quantity=A.Quantity 
                                   and Protein =A.Protein
                                   and Carb    =A.Carb
                                   -- Add your other fields here
                                 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From (Select Distinct 
              Quantity
             ,Protein
             ,Carb
             -- Add your other fields here
        From  YourTable ) A
```